# Populate sharepoint list column based on another column value

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2010 List with two columns, `State` and `City`. `State` is populated with a list of states while `City` is populated with a list of cities. The `City` list also has a `State` column. I want to filter the `City` list according to the selected state. How can I achieve this without using InfoPath, SharePoint Designer or a web part. I want to do it only in SharePoint. Is that possible to give a message when they select the city stating "Please select State before selecting a City"? If any JQuery or JavaScript will be used then how can I use that.

Comment: how many lists do you have in total?

Comment: Check this **[SharePoint Auto Populate Column based on another Column](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-populate-column-based-on-another-column/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Managed Metadata instead. Create a tree with the states and the cities and then add that as a column instead.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-key.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript, but to do it you need either Sharepoint Designer or a web part .... So in JavaScript you could use [SPService](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) or [SPJS](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/20/convert-text-fields-to-cascading-dropdowns-unlimited-number-of-levels/)